# Reshape a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame that looks like

```
F1      F2        Number
Banana  Apple     9
Orange  Banana    7
Apple   Orange    8
Banana  Orange    6
```

I need to convert this to

```
Type    F1   F2
Banana  15   7
Orange  7    14
Apple   8    9
```

Comment: The numbers don't add up...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
setNames(merge(aggregate(Number ~ F1, dat, sum),
               aggregate(Number ~ F2, dat, sum),
               by.x = "F1", by.y = "F2", all = TRUE),
         c("Type", "F1", "F2"))

#     Type F1 F2
# 1  Apple  8  9
# 2 Banana 15  7
# 3 Orange  7 14
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Comment: What if I have differing number of rows? In F1, three kinds and In F2, four kinds.

Comment: @user2684128 See the update. Now, it works even if there is a differing number of rows.

Comment: I have a data frame that looks like

    Date     Type    Number
    01/01/14   M1       9
    01/01/14   M2       7
    01/02/14   M1       8
    01/02/14   M2       6

I need to convert this to

    Date       M1      M2 
    01/01/14   9       7
    01/02/14   8       6

Comment: I used dcast(df, Date ~ Type) Great! I love reshape2

Answer (score 1):

This problem can also be tackled pretty easily with the "reshape2" package:

```
library(reshape2)

x <- melt(mydf, id.vars="Number")
dcast(x, value ~ variable, value.var="Number", fun.aggregate=sum)
#    value F1 F2
# 1  Apple  8  9
# 2 Banana 15  7
# 3 Orange  7 14
```

---

However, it is also pretty easily tackled with base R:

```
xtabs(Number ~ values + ind, 
      cbind(mydf["Number"], 
            stack(mydf[setdiff(names(mydf), "Number")])))
#         ind
# values   F1 F2
#   Apple   8  9
#   Banana 15  7
#   Orange  7 14
```

In cases where your data are already long, as they are in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267706/reshape-a-data-frame-in-r#comment32177546_21267804), it is even more straightforward:

```
xtabs(Number ~ Date + Type, mydf)
#           Type
# Date       M1 M2
#   01/01/14  9  7
#   01/02/14  8  6
```